# Stream.pipe() to a variable in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, streaming

Just starting out with Node, and I am running into a small hiccup: I am trying to write the output from a stream to a variable in my code. However, it seems that only STDOUT will work.  Is it possible to pipe the output to a string?  Many thanks

```
var userData = null;

s3.GetObject(getOptions, { stream : true }, function(err, data) {
    fmt.dump(err, 'err');
    fmt.dump(data, 'data');

   // stream the file to a var

    fmt.sep();
    fmt.title('User data file:');
    data.Stream.pipe(userData);
    data.Stream.on('end', function() {
        fmt.sep();
    });
});
```

This code throws the following error:

_stream_readable.js:476
  dest.on('unpipe', onunpipe);
       ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'on' of null

Comment: You can only pipe to another stream.  What are you trying to do with the result? You may want `concat-stream`.

Comment: thanks, SLaks, will try that now

Answer (score -1):

if your userData = null, it would throw an error, it needs data